# How to determine argument behavior of a function based on an interface property that is a union type?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that takes a function that can be either a function type or a string (for async functions so tsc doesn't transpile them). The problem is on my task runner, I can't seem to figure out how to determine argument behavior of the function based on this `func` property on the interface. It infers it as `string | (...args: any[]) => number)` for instance on `func: (x: number) => x + 1)`. The problem with this is when I try checking the func arguments in the `run` function call to make it require arguments on functions that take arguments, it isn't properly checking that it extends function and it's inferring the arguments as `any[]` rather than `number`. Anyone know how to do something like this?

Example of what I mean here:

```
interface ITask<T> {
    id: number;
    func: ((...args: any[]) => T) | string;
};

class Task<T> implements ITask<T> {
    public id: number;
    public func: ((...args: any[]) => T) | string;

    constructor(opts: ITask<T>) {
        this.id = opts.id;
        this.func = opts.func;
    }
}

class Runner {
    constructor() { }
    public run<T>(task: { func: T }, ...args: T extends (...args: infer Args) => any ? Args : any[]) {
        if (typeof task.func === 'function')
            return task.func(...args);
        else
            return eval(`(${task.func})`);
    }
}

const task = new Task({ id: 1, func: (x: number) => x + 1 });

const runner = new Runner();
// should be expecting an argument, but func is not inferring from usage it's a function and not a string
runner.run(task);
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBU4GcDWAedAPmQG8BYAKGWuWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbkpuRgsQCJgApRAOilwoAcyxM4IAJ4BtALoBKZAF5i6bQB9kWMFFCzeFAL5XKCADbYsyTLgLFgbAA4OIbCHAXDGx8IlI+Gm8WDgdgBFpGZnYuKCt+aNj4gSERZHEpCRl5RRUNbT1XIxMzCzsqGgQAexBTKBYEMCaoUSbvMAU0NzDCbXIG-mowAAtgLAl6XWQ+gYW6dMmp2fnBYSWVndyN6mtKU4p7JywXACUhEGgIieRm1rMOrp6x5HOMmLiEu0QB5RGBQkwSDlhEx0D8ADTIQrFQawiAAD0gIDoLkk0jkg1AMEeAEF8RViEplMgAPzIUnyZClNRaJ6bajAGD5MDKbwQJqcsG4CS7BI6MXIADkIrAwBaEs0kTZNCgEDALCgIGQgpwwtyuKKZOOkwgDiwEEVSuQKrVGuQEAAbnAHKIAAaiAAkJG1uuE1k0Ls0RvO53sLVMWtCSweAHdXKFRJD6EwAIwIkViNFMVicaDk5Bo5AAamQyZ+gcoobeVvujx0zAgsbuIAeXysAHo2yZpk0WA46MguHa0bzOhZkEpx3J2IEwAiOCwwFCEnNmE1F4ToOYQLIBFAmmxkCwsHBZChgGAJS44EuZS1x1jV4vr20LJQgS2JEDQaFyxQgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the compiler to remember enough about the type of the `func` property to know what it's arguments are, you need the generic type parameter to encompass those arguments.  Your `ITask<T>` has `T` only represent the return type of `func` if it's a function, and the argument types are `any[]`, which is not generic at all.  Here is a different possible typing which is capable of keeping track of function arguments and return types:

```
interface ITask<F extends string | ((...args: any) => any)> {
    id: number;
    func: F;
};
```

Here the `func` property is just the generic type `F`, which has been [constrained](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to either be a function type or a string.

The definition of `Task` changes accordingly:

```
class Task<F extends string | ((...args: any) => any)> implements ITask<F> {
    public id: number;
    public func: F
    constructor(opts: ITask<F>) {
        this.id = opts.id;
        this.func = opts.func;
    }
}
```

Your `Runner` class stays more or less the same (that `eval()` scares me though).  You may or may not want to more strongly type its return (which was just `any` before):

```
class Runner {
    constructor() { }
    public run<T>(
        task: { func: T },
        ...args: T extends (...args: infer Args) => any ? Args : any[]
    ): T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any {
        if (typeof task.func === 'function')
            return task.func(...args);
        else
            return eval(`(${task.func})`);
    }
}
```

And now you get this behavior:

```
const task = new Task({ id: 1, func: (x: number) => x + 1 });
const runner = new Runner();
runner.run(task); // error! expected 2 arguments but got one
const numVal = runner.run(task, 10); // okay
// const numVal: number;

const anyVal = runner.run(new Task({ id: 2, func: "someString" })); //okay
// const anyVal: any;
```

This all looks reasonable to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBU4GcDWAeAMWQgA9IQATLZLMKUAc2QB9kAKNgOm7igawBcyOCACeASmQBeAHzCx4uQG8AsAChkm5MApCQAVwC2AI2gBudVuQx9IBEIIW1AXyfqEAG2zVMuQsTIISmpaehAmVg5uTl5+IREJaTkExW1DAAcPCEMgsGoMbHwCZUstdP1jD2AEbV1kAxNzUs1yyurrW3tkAmbkBAB7EFD9BDB+qDZ+9LyhAr9iyVUNKy0wAAtgLE4daWQpvO2KJxXVja2bO139887jrWd1B7V3LyxqACVbEGhkJasBoZ0EZjCaLZBPKytKo1KC2PDoGRsXpWMCFIRKDp2ITocEAGmRWmisUEyBxpHIVHYRL4JNAMB+AEEaZJZPJRMgAPzIJn8ZDxMQAbQAur1xNiAhTqFweDT+YlWXSfu9OchlXLfgTNMAYOwwKJ0hB+jrUbhOBcalJLcgAOTmsDAQbW8SalZQCBgfRQEDIE04M2daUxZl3E4QDxYCAuqxuj1e4gANzgHjYAAM2AASJS+-12ZziFPiEPgx7qdyDWg+wq7b4Ad1JhTYGJ0QgAjLjMV02CQ9EZTFAWXISMgANTIFvgwtlwHIWEgb5QasQOufOfQNiTtSz+ecWdsX2F5AAekPxCgUHGAEIAgbRhAKMgAEzCPhGXLUYz6MDIBj9L+DSNqACFYNAAakmuxbtAO62HuhTti2AAMB7HnsOBwKI6goUBX6gUmPaNFAbiAeWX4JGBHgQV8UG7rW9a4I2tRCA+7bmkIABEWD9DkADKdCMGxE7IYe-RoRhahYSRbLkXKZhAA)

Comment: First off, thanks for your response. I should have been more clear in my original post, however. This is for a threadpool that I'm writing in what is essentially a project where I'm copying fp-ts line for line to learn how it works. Problem is that when I have something like that, then the HKT magic fp-ts uses doesn't work to transform Task into a monad. Here's how I currently have task: https://github.com/adekau/airo/blob/master/src/Threads/Task.ts
and the problem occurs when trying to declare the hkt module, for example: https://github.com/adekau/airo/blob/master/src/Monad/Either.ts

Comment: With type param "A" is not assignable to "string"

Comment: Figured it out! https://github.com/adekau/airo/commit/d1faf2c8eefee2a0d24ec0594071032489637ec1